# telnet will exit after a period of time

Tags: timeout, telnet

Recently I am working on an embedded project, and for some reason, it doesn't contain ssh or other tools like this except telnet, I have to use telnet.

But after days of working, I'm annoyed by the automatic close of the connection (not exact automatically, but you have to type something in it, then it will quit the telnet).

Here is the details:

I login into a remote embedded system, then leave it there and do something outside this terminal or just wait, after 2 mins(120s), I type a command in the telnet session, it will display:

```
~ # Connection closed by foreign host.
```

then exit the telnet, and I have to connect to it again using telnet.

On the first sight, I thought maybe there is some configuration such like timeout about telnet in the embedded system, but I found nothing, and I told the timeout to my colleague, and he tried to telnet into it (in Xshell) on his Windows PC and wait it for 2 mins, it works fine, and he said that that problem never happened him.

So I thought maybe I had some configuration in my system (CentOS 6.5 32-bit), but didn't find anything either.

So I guessed, may it was the problem of my shell, I was using fish-shell, so I tried it in bash-shell, but it was the same in bash-shell, so I tried another terminal, the same result.

So I tried it without tmux, the same result.

So then I got a Windows PC in my VirtualBox which was installed in my CentOS6.5 32-bit, and I tried to telnet into the embedded system using Xshell, and it exited more quickly, less than 2 minutes.

So I don't know what to do? Does anyone know how to avoid the problem?

Comment: The message "Connection closed by foreign host." means that the server closed the connection. It has nothing to do with your client or client-system. It's all on the server side. Then if it's configurable or not is another question, that should probably be posted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead (if the server uses a standard telnet server).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought that too, check out the first part of my guesses when this problem occurred to me in my post.